# Input type hidden passes the same value from foreach in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a code with foreach which prints the image and then it will stores the image id in hidden form field. I want to get the particular image id when user clicks the particular image . But it returns the first value of foreach image id . Sorry for bad english . Somebody please help me with this.

```
<div id="gallery_09" >
    <?php foreach ($hair['hair_color_media'] as $key => $row){?>
   <input type = "hidden" name = "hair_color_slug" value = "<?=$row->hair_color_slug?>">
   <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$row->hair_color?>" data-update="" data-image="<?=base_url('assets/img/products/large/'.$row->media_images);?>" data-zoom-image="<?=base_url('assets/img/products/large/'.$row->media_images);?>" onclick = "getPrice();">
      <img data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$row->hair_color?>" src="<?=base_url('assets/img/products/pin/'.$row->media_images);?>" width="50" style = "border-radius: 50%;">
  </a>
<?php }?>
  </div>
<input type = "text" readonly="" id ="color" name = "color"/>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getPrice()
        {
            var color = $('input:hidden[name=hair_color_slug]').val();

            document.getElementById('color').value = color;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: nAME for the input must be unique to fetch data, `<input type = "hidden" name = "hair_color_slug<?=$key?>" value = "<?=$row->hair_color_slug?>">` replace with this

Comment: Give common class to all inputs. and fetch the data of that class

Comment: This should not be using a hidden input field to begin with - not if the only purpose is to get access to that value inside the getPrice function. Output this value as a _custom data attribute_ directly on the `a` element instead, and then go read it from there.

Comment: @quickSwap how do I call that hidden field inside js ? I'm using this > var color = $('input:hidden[name=hair_color_slug]').val(); If I change that input name with id, how do I get that ?

Comment: There is no call, there is access. `var data = []; $(".customclass").each(function(x,y){ 
var v = $(this).val();
 data.push(v) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the handler 'this' keyword within getPrice function to obtain the current element which fired the event.

```
onclick = "getPrice(this);
```

On click will get the previous hidden value of clicks element and put in the color field.

```
function getPrice(getprice)
{
    var color = $(getprice).prev().val();

    document.getElementById('color').value = color;
}
```

Comment: hi farooq, Try this code, it will solve your problem.